# TranspilerError: 'The input circuit None is not scheduled'

Tags: qiskit, programming

The following error occurs when executing the code to measure the dephasing time(T2). I would appreciate it if someone could give me a solution to this problem. Among the two functions below, widthoutDelay() performs normally, and the function withDelay() fails with the attached error.

Additionally, where can I find an example code to measure the time-dependent dephasing of the qubit? Some of the sample codes are from a few years ago, so there are a lot of contents that have been depreciated.

```
--------------------------- Execution Code in jupyter ---------------------------

from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute,IBMQ
from qiskit.tools.monitor import job_monitor
from qiskit import transpile
import numpy

pi = numpy.pi

IBMQ.load_account()
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q')
backend = provider.get_backend('ibm_nairobi')

q = QuantumRegister(1,'q')
c = ClassicalRegister(1,'c')

def withoutDelay():
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(q,c)

    circuit.h(q[0])
    circuit.h(q[0])
    circuit.measure(q[0],c[0]) #Measuring the qubit

    nShots = 8192

    job = execute(circuit, backend, shots=nShots)
    job_monitor(job)

    counts = job.result().get_counts()

    print("No delay: ",counts)

def withDelay():  
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(q,c)
    circuit.h(q[0])
    circuit.delay(283, unit="us") # Delay of 200.79 microseconds   
    circuit.h(q[0])

    circuit.measure(q[0],c[0]) #Measuring the qubit

    transpiled_circ = transpile(circuit, backend, scheduling_method='alap')  

    nShots = 8192
    
    job = execute(transpiled_circ, backend, shots=nShots)
    job_monitor(job)

    counts = job.result().get_counts()

    print("With delay: ",counts)

withoutDelay()
withDelay()
```

```
--------------------------- Error Message ---------------------------

Job Status: job has successfully run
No delay:  {'0': 8111, '1': 81}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TranspilerError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [19], in ()
     49     print("With delay: ",counts)
     51 withoutDelay()
---> 52 withDelay()

Input In [19], in withDelay()
     40 transpiled_circ = transpile(circuit, backend, scheduling_method='alap')  
     42 nShots = 8192
---> 44 job = execute(transpiled_circ, backend, shots=nShots)
     45 job_monitor(job)
     47 counts = job.result().get_counts()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/qiskit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/execute_function.py:299, in execute(experiments, backend, basis_gates, coupling_map, backend_properties, initial_layout, seed_transpiler, optimization_level, pass_manager, qobj_id, qobj_header, shots, memory, max_credits, seed_simulator, default_qubit_los, default_meas_los, qubit_lo_range, meas_lo_range, schedule_los, meas_level, meas_return, memory_slots, memory_slot_size, rep_time, rep_delay, parameter_binds, schedule_circuit, inst_map, meas_map, scheduling_method, init_qubits, **run_config)
    296     experiments = pass_manager.run(experiments)
    297 else:
    298     # transpiling the circuits using given transpile options
--> 299     experiments = transpile(
    300         experiments,
    301         basis_gates=basis_gates,
    302         coupling_map=coupling_map,
    303         backend_properties=backend_properties,
    304         initial_layout=initial_layout,
    305         seed_transpiler=seed_transpiler,
    306         optimization_level=optimization_level,
    307         backend=backend,
    308     )
    310 if schedule_circuit:
    311     experiments = schedule(
    312         circuits=experiments,
    313         backend=backend,
   (...)
    316         method=scheduling_method,
    317     )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/qiskit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/compiler/transpiler.py:341, in transpile(circuits, backend, basis_gates, inst_map, coupling_map, backend_properties, initial_layout, layout_method, routing_method, translation_method, scheduling_method, instruction_durations, dt, approximation_degree, timing_constraints, seed_transpiler, optimization_level, callback, output_name, unitary_synthesis_method, unitary_synthesis_plugin_config, target)
    338     for circuit, unique_args in zip(circuits, unique_transpile_args):
    339         transpile_config, pass_manager = _combine_args(shared_args, unique_args)
    340         output_circuits.append(
--> 341             _serial_transpile_circuit(
    342                 circuit,
    343                 pass_manager,
    344                 transpile_config["callback"],
    345                 transpile_config["output_name"],
    346                 transpile_config["backend_num_qubits"],
    347                 transpile_config["faulty_qubits_map"],
    348                 transpile_config["pass_manager_config"].backend_properties,
    349             )
    350         )
    351     circuits = output_circuits
    352 end_time = time()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/qiskit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/compiler/transpiler.py:434, in _serial_transpile_circuit(circuit, pass_manager, callback, output_name, num_qubits, faulty_qubits_map, backend_prop)
    425 def _serial_transpile_circuit(
    426     circuit,
    427     pass_manager,
   (...)
    432     backend_prop=None,
    433 ):
--> 434     result = pass_manager.run(circuit, callback=callback, output_name=output_name)
    435     if faulty_qubits_map:
    436         return _remap_circuit_faulty_backend(
    437             result,
    438             num_qubits,
    439             backend_prop,
    440             faulty_qubits_map,
    441         )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/qiskit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/passmanager.py:507, in StagedPassManager.run(self, circuits, output_name, callback)
    500 def run(
    501     self,
    502     circuits: Union[QuantumCircuit, List[QuantumCircuit]],
    503     output_name: str = None,
    504     callback: Callable = None,
    505 ) -> Union[QuantumCircuit, List[QuantumCircuit]]:
    506     self._update_passmanager()
--> 507     return super().run(circuits, output_name, callback)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/qiskit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/passmanager.py:224, in PassManager.run(self, circuits, output_name, callback)
    222     return circuits
    223 if isinstance(circuits, QuantumCircuit):
--> 224     return self._run_single_circuit(circuits, output_name, callback)
    225 if len(circuits) == 1:
    226     return self._run_single_circuit(circuits[0], output_name, callback)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/qiskit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/passmanager.py:279, in PassManager._run_single_circuit(self, circuit, output_name, callback)
    267 """Run all the passes on a ``circuit``.
    268 
    269 Args:
   (...)
    276     The transformed circuit.
    277 """
    278 running_passmanager = self._create_running_passmanager()
--> 279 result = running_passmanager.run(circuit, output_name=output_name, callback=callback)
    280 self.property_set = running_passmanager.property_set
    281 return result

File ~/anaconda3/envs/qiskit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/runningpassmanager.py:124, in RunningPassManager.run(***failed resolving arguments***)
    122 for passset in self.working_list:
    123     for pass_ in passset:
--> 124         dag = self._do_pass(pass_, dag, passset.options)
    126 circuit = dag_to_circuit(dag)
    127 if output_name:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/qiskit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/runningpassmanager.py:167, in RunningPassManager._do_pass(self, pass_, dag, options)
    165 # Run the pass itself, if not already run
    166 if pass_ not in self.valid_passes:
--> 167     dag = self._run_this_pass(pass_, dag)
    169     # update the valid_passes property
    170     self._update_valid_passes(pass_)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/qiskit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/runningpassmanager.py:221, in RunningPassManager._run_this_pass(self, pass_, dag)
    218 elif pass_.is_analysis_pass:
    219     # Measure time if we have a callback or logging set
    220     start_time = time()
--> 221     pass_.run(FencedDAGCircuit(dag))
    222     end_time = time()
    223     run_time = end_time - start_time

File ~/anaconda3/envs/qiskit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/passes/scheduling/alignments/reschedule.py:206, in ConstrainedReschedule.run(self, dag)
    170 """Run rescheduler.
    171 
    172 This pass should perform rescheduling to satisfy:
   (...)
    202     TranspilerError: If circuit is not scheduled.
    203 """
    205 if "node_start_time" not in self.property_set:
--> 206     raise TranspilerError(
    207         f"The input circuit {dag.name} is not scheduled. Call one of scheduling passes "
    208         f"before running the {self.__class__.__name__} pass."
    209     )
    211 node_start_time = self.property_set["node_start_time"]
    213 for node in dag.topological_op_nodes():

TranspilerError: 'The input circuit None is not scheduled. Call one of scheduling passes before running the ConstrainedReschedule pass.'
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your `withDelay` function is its use of `execute` (which combines `transpile` and `backend.run` into a single function call). When you're calling `execute`, it's the equivalent of running `transpile` again without specifying a scheduling method.

You can fix the issue simply by changing `execute` to `backend.run`, so the revised `withDelay` function would look as follows:

```
def withDelay():  
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(q,c)
    circuit.h(q[0])
    circuit.delay(283, unit="us") # Delay of 200.79 microseconds   
    circuit.h(q[0])

    circuit.measure(q[0],c[0]) #Measuring the qubit

    transpiled_circ = transpile(circuit, backend, scheduling_method='alap')  

    nShots = 8192
    
    job = backend.run(transpiled_circ, shots=nShots)
    job_monitor(job)

    counts = job.result().get_counts()

    print("With delay: ",counts)
```

See related issue: [Transpiler error during execution of circuits... #7317](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/7317)